# How to convert one byte and 4 bits from another byte to a short using bitwise?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and

Using bitwise, how could we convert these 3 bytes to two shorts in this pattern in the most performant way?:
**(11111111)(01111110)(10000001) 3 bytes**
**(111111110111)(111010000001) 2 shorts**
Found a way to combine two bytes into a short, but for a combination of 1 byte and 4 bits tried a variety of ways for hours with no success. Thanks for your help.

```
byte byt1 = -1; // 11111111
byte byt2 = 126;// 01111110
byte byt3 = 129;// 10000001
short s_1_2 = (short) ((byt1 << 8) | (byt2 & 0xFF));
// value is 1111111101111110
short s1 = // want to be 111111110111
short s2 = // want to be 111010000001
```

Comment: If you go from byte to String and then to short? That approach may work with any combination. So in the end you will lose non of the 1s and 0s.

Comment: *...and 4 bits from another byte...*. *Which* 4 bits?

Comment: @g00se as the pattern in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possibilities is the following:

```java
short s1 = (short) (((byt1 & 0xff) << 4) | ((byt2 & 0xf0) >> 4));
short s2 = (short) (((byt2 & 0x0f) << 8) | (byt3 & 0xff));
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you please explain how to combine these two shorts into one int? Considering `111111110111` and `111010000001` to become `111111110111111010000001`

Comment: I'm doing it this way: `int int_num = ((s1 & 0xfff)<<12)|(s2 & 0xfff);
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(int_num));` The result is correct but if there is any note to mention?

Comment: @Eftekhari your method is correct.